# Не могу вывести произвольное поле в шаблоне archive-product.php

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть сайт на wordpress (с плагином woocomerce). Пытаюсь добавить произвольное поле "Редактор WYSIWYG" он же tinyMCE (хотя и обычное текстовое поле тоже не выводиться), в категорию товара, будет дополнительное описание категории товара под самими товарами. Поле добавляю через плагин Advanced Custom Fields, имя поля "desc". Проблема в том, что не могу вывести никаким кодом это произвольное поле в файле archive-product.php, вот примеры полей которые пытался ставить:

```
<?php the_field('desc'); ?>
```

`<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'desc', true); ?>`

```
<?php if($desc=get_field("desc")){echo $desc;}?>
```

но ничего не вышло. Помогите пожалуйста. Прикрепляю код файла  archive-product.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying product archives, including the main shop page which is a post type archive.
 *
 * Override this template by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
global $zorka_data,$woocommerce_loop;

$archive_layout = isset($_GET['layout']) ? $_GET['layout'] : '' ;
$layouts = array('full-content','left-sidebar','right-sidebar');
if (!in_array($archive_layout,$layouts)) {

    $cat = get_queried_object();
    if ($cat && property_exists( $cat, 'term_id' )) {
        $archive_layout = get_tax_meta( $cat,'zorka_custom_product_archive_layout');
    }

    if (empty($archive_layout) || $archive_layout == 'none') {
        $archive_layout = $zorka_data['product-archive-layout'];
    }
}

$archive_product_columns = isset($_GET['columns']) ? $_GET['columns'] : '';
if (!in_array($archive_product_columns,array('2','3','4'))) {
    $archive_product_columns = isset($zorka_data['archive-product-columns']) ? $zorka_data['archive-product-columns'] : 3;
}

$class_col = 'col-md-12';

if ($archive_layout == 'left-sidebar' || $archive_layout == 'right-sidebar' ){
    $class_col = 'col-md-9';
}
if ($archive_layout == 'left-sidebar') {
    $class_col .= ' col-md-push-3';
}
get_header();
?>
<?php get_template_part('archive-product','top') ?>
<main role="main" class="site-content-product-archive">
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="<?php echo esc_attr($class_col); ?>">
                <div class="product-wrapper clearfix">
                    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                    <div class="category-filter clearfix">
                        <?php
                        /**
                         * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook
                         *
                         * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
                         * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
                         */
                        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(array(
                        'before' => '<div class="product-cat-wrap clearfix">',
                        'after' => '</div>',

                    ));
                        $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $archive_product_columns; ?>

                    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                        <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

                    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

                    <?php
                    /**
                     * woocommerce_after_shop_loop hook
                     *
                     * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
                     */
                    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
                    ?>

                <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>
                    <?php wc_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' ); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>




                <div><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, ' desc_acf ', true); ?></div>



            </div>
            </div>

            <?php
            if ($archive_layout == 'left-sidebar') {
                get_sidebar('shop-left');
            }
            if ($archive_layout == 'right-sidebar') {
                get_sidebar('shop');
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: У ACF наименование полей своё. См документацию к плагу.

Comment: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/wysiwyg-editor/
тут написано что так нужно: '<?php the_field('wysiwyg_test'); ?>' но всё ровно не показывается ничего

Comment: хмм. раньше ACF добавлял был префикс (`acf_` или др, не помню ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

`<?php the_field('desc', 'category_7'); ?>`

**7** - это ID категории. 
Если у вас произвольная таксономия, например products_cat, то нужно делать так:

`<?php the_field('desc', 'products_cat_7'); ?>`